# git repo issue related puppet

Tags: linux, git, github, puppet

I am new in `git` world and recently i have started deploying puppet. I am planing to put puppet in `git` version control. I am following cookbook of puppet and doing following

```
root@cookbook:/etc/puppet# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /etc/puppet/.git/
root@cookbook:/etc/puppet# git add manifests/ modules/
root@cookbook:/etc/puppet# git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) c7a24cf] initial commit
59 files changed, 1790 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 manifests/site.pp
create mode 100644 manifests/utils.pp
```

When i am running following command i got this error. what is command going to do??

```
root@cookbook:/etc/puppet# git push -u origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

how do i connect to git and checkout my repo on my client or somewhere else?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` outputs?

Comment: git remote -v `empty` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell git where the remote repository is located:

```
git remote add origin <url-of-remote>
```

Edit: `origin` is simply a conventional name of your main remote, much like `master` is for your main branch.

Comment: `<url-of-remote>` ?? like this `git://myserver/`

Comment: @Satish This depends on the configuration of the server you're pushing/pulling to/from. Example urls can be: `git@mydomain.com:myapp/myapp.git` or `https://mydomain.com/myapp/myapp.git`

Comment: `myapp.git` ?? i didn't define it anywhere? how do i know what name is that in my case? or where to define? sorry for pushy because i am not clear about full URL

Comment: @Satish that was an example. This depends on the setup of the remote server. More info here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: I just install git using `yum install git` do you think i need to configure git first? where is the config file i can setup URL etc.

Comment: @Satish the link in my previous comment is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done a git init in the /etc/puppet folder it is already 'origin' and you don't have to push.

I think you just wanted to add the files to the master branch. You already did this with your commit. Try git log